# iOS & iCloud: Broken iCloud data causes kbd process to crash constantly and drains battery

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, battery, crash

On Stackoverflow I was told to come here.
Since a few days ago my iPhone 5 is getting unusually warm and the battery drains REALLY quick, like in 4-5 hours. I tried turning all the usual suspecty off (location service, cellular data, push, etc.) but no change. Now, when looking through the crash logs on the device, I found a huge number of crash reports for the kbd process. There is a crash log every  ~30-60 minutes and they all contain something like this:

```
Incident Identifier: F4DC2DF2-8E84-4054-8028-F62C84D7A780
CrashReporter Key:   31ad5b6da61a3170f593b441e57647ee0c2cff72
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         kbd [1589]
Path:            /Applications/kbd.app/kbd
Identifier:      kbd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-14 23:00:20.102 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.4 (10B350)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00180fc8
Crashed Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bf51e30 0x3bf51000 + 3632
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bf51fd0 0x3bf51000 + 4048
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33d482b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33d46fd6 __CFRunLoopRun + 814
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33cba238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33cba0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x345de5be 0x345da000 + 17854
7   Foundation                      0x34681c40 0x345da000 + 687168
8   kbd                             0x0009fbc2 0x9f000 + 3010
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3be9bb1c 0x3be9a000 + 6940

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3beab014 szone_malloc_should_clear + 12
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3beaafd4 malloc_zone_malloc + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33d572ce __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 902
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33d5636c __CFStringAppendBytes + 616
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33d53c90 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 9208
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33ccb89e _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 70
6   Foundation                      0x346134f2 0x345da000 + 234738
7   Foundation                      0x3461320e 0x345da000 + 233998
8   CoreFoundation                  0x33d0a036 -[__NSCFNumber descriptionWithLocale:] + 58
9   Foundation                      0x345dc1ec 0x345da000 + 8684
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33d5442e __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11158
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33ccb89e _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 70
12  Foundation                      0x345e2404 0x345da000 + 33796
13  CoreData                        0x33bc764e 0x33af8000 + 849486
14  CoreData                        0x33bc7594 0x33af8000 + 849300
15  CoreData                        0x33c5d2bc 0x33af8000 + 1462972
16  CoreData                        0x33c5944e 0x33af8000 + 1446990
17  CoreData                        0x33c5947e 0x33af8000 + 1447038
18  CoreData                        0x33c5947e 0x33af8000 + 1447038

...

507 CoreData                        0x33c5947e 0x33af8000 + 1447038
508 CoreData                        0x33c5947e 0x33af8000 + 1447038
509 CoreData                        0x33c5947e 0x33af8000 + 1447038
510 CoreData                        0x33c5947e 0x33af8000 + 1447038

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bf525d0 0x3bf51000 + 5584
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3be8dd22 0x3be87000 + 27938
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3be89374 0x3be87000 + 9076

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x000ae000    r1: 0x00000080      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x33d2547d
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x000ae000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x00181034
    r8: 0x000ae000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x214cfa00     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x3c0bbaac    sp: 0x00180fbc      lr: 0x3beaafd7      pc: 0x3beab014
  cpsr: 0x40000030

Binary Images:
   0x9f000 -    0xa7fff +kbd armv7s  <47657f4dd979300a840367905786eccc> /Applications/kbd.app/kbd
0x2fe0e000 - 0x2fe2efff  dyld armv7s  <67efe80b9d863d6bb30fe51e6e17b070> /usr/lib/dyld
0x32f6f000 - 0x32f6ffff  Accelerate armv7s  <f4e8c4c464953429ab6bd3160aadd176> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x32f70000 - 0x330adfff  vImage armv7s  <49d3cf19d0a23f4d836fc313e5fd6bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x330ae000 - 0x3319afff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <584e045442be39fc847ffe1a5e4c99b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3319b000 - 0x33451fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <30a3e7dd8c603a9d81b5e42704ba5971> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x33452000 - 0x334aafff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <936354553eb93d2dafa76ffcad65f9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x334ab000 - 0x334bdfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <5fae8715a0403315bb1991b79677f916> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x334be000 - 0x334befff  vecLib armv7s  <30275ee8819331229ba21256d7b94596> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x334bf000 - 0x334d0fff  Accounts armv7s  <df3255c62b0239f4995bc14ea79f106b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x334d2000 - 0x33536fff  AddressBook armv7s  <ea949de12ca93a6a96ef80d0cb4d9231> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x339c8000 - 0x33a8dfff  CFNetwork armv7s  <ef41814d8641319c96cdeb1264d2d150> 

...

0x3bf9c000 - 0x3bf9dfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <85e91e99abc03db88eddc665424090b4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3bf9e000 - 0x3bf9efff  libunwind.dylib armv7s  <3b7ec561dbec3a199f09ea08a64e76ee> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3bf9f000 - 0x3bfb4fff  libxpc.dylib armv7s  <0562a59bdf8d3f7783e93f35d7e724a8> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Any idea what is causing this or even what exactly the kbd process does? I really would appreciate any help since this is really a big issue and my iPhone has become basically unusable. Thanks!

EDIT: I narrowed the problem down to broken data in iCloud. As soon as I turn "Documents & Data" in Settings off, the crashes and battery drain disappear. Still couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like you're on iOS 6.1.4, so not jailbroken. You could try backing up and doing a full restore of your device. I'm afraid that even if we could trace down the error there's nothing you can do to fix it.

If you're an iOS developer, though, I might go over to bugreport.apple.com and file this bug along with any details you may think are relevant.

Comment: I tried a full restore but restored from an iCloud backup. Also, I noticed that the crashes appear to only happen when I'm not on Wifi and using cellular data.