# iPhone 6 keyboard freezing when typing on iOS 8 (com.apple.TextInput.kbd)

Tags: keyboard, ios, text-input, iphone

I had an iPhone 5 before upgrading and its keyboard never froze on iOS 8, but with my iPhone 6 it is happening all the time. I already redefined my keyboard dictionary.

Bringing up console I see a error on TextInput:

```
Nov 18 11:19:27 GBFGabriel-iPhone-6 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TextInput.kbd) <Notice>: Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 3 seconds.
```

Anyone has any idea why is this happening/how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little more digging I found that the problem was with the kbd process using tons of memory when I tried to write something. Google search with "kbd process" bring me a lot of useful links:

[iOS & iCloud: Broken iCloud data causes kbd process to crash constantly and drains battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91382/ios-icloud-broken-icloud-data-causes-kbd-process-to-crash-constantly-and-drai)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5521035

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1615584

What did worked for me was turning iCloud drive off and on again.

EDIT:
So it turned out I was dumb enough to turn iCloud Drive off and don't turn it on again!
Been using it this way for some 2 months.

But I've got the solution! (Mac only) I was digging through my iCloud files at `~/Library/Mobile Documents/` and found that there is a folder with the same name of the evil process.

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput
```

I opened it up and decided to read some files, unzip here, convert plist there (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179410/how-to-open-icloud-cdt-file) and voilá: in just one file, the process kbd tried to insert a word 147 thousand times. This entry was a correction from "mongolao" to "mongolão" (southern Brazilian idiom in Portuguese for a vulgar use of the word "retarded"), ironic. As there were lots of these files, I think with myself that the problem is that somehow the kbd process fell into a loophole, and I decided to delete all the content of the `com~apple~TextInput` folder.

Waited a few minutes for my mac to upload the changes, turned iCloud Drive off and on again on my iPhone and...... working! If I don't come back here to edit this answer it means this was it! (or I forgot something really stupid again)

Oh, and don't even try to boot up Finder to do this, be a good stackExchange user and only use Terminal. (Pro tip: Yosemite breaks the iCloud folder in Finder)

EDIT 3 (3 months later):

**tldr**: run the following on your Mac's terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~TextInput
rm -rf *
```

Comment: I had this terrible issue since I enabled iCloud drive. It was really frustrating. I wasn't able to write on device for 1019€ single sentence without interrupting. I also tryed to contact Apple support without any successful help. But your advice solved the problem! Thank you Gabriel!

Comment: Updating this history: I've bought an iPhone 6 Plus (awesome device, I shouldn't have bought the iPhone 6) and there it goes: this shit all over again. Thanks old me for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I manage to open some cdt files in plist format. And I see some translations I've added to my phone. How do you see that your phrase was applied 147´000 times?

What did you delete? I'm afraid to delete the wrong stuff :)

<s>*So, what was the contents of the `com~apple~TextInput` catalog. I have this exact issue and it's beginning to be frustrating not being able to type more than, say, 5 characters before the keyboard freezes.
My contents are the directories `Documents`and `Dictionaries`, where the `Dictionaries` catalog contains the two folders `.baseline` and `.cdmetadata`, *files with names like `mobile.23489DF9-CD89-...` and `mobile~9273434-28347...`, no extensions here at all.* From your comment I expected some .cdt or .zip-files at least.
What did you delete? I'm afraid to delete the wrong stuff :)
EDIT: sorry, I found the .cdt files*</s>

Comment: I deleted everything inside `com~apple~TextInput`, seriously. It's working like a charm ;). I counted the words by using the word counter in TextWrangler (any text editor might have this functionality).